# UDP client messages not received on a remote server

Tags: udp, client-server

Tried to implement a very simple Java Tutorials example "Writing a Datagram Client and Server" (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html). It works perfectly well on a local network. However, when the server is on a remote address the client's UDP message never gets to the server.

I'm using port 32 for communications. The firewall and antivirus software are disabled on both the client and server computers. The router on the server local network is set to forward UDP port 32 packets to the server host local address. The same is done for the client router. The `netstat -an` command on the server computer shows

```
 UDP    0.0.0.0:32             *:*



 UDP    [::]:32                *:*
```

Wireshark on the client computer shows that the client message is being sent to the correct IP address of the remote server computer (obtained on the server by the "what is my ip"). However, Wireshark on the remote server shows no message received whatsoever on UDP port 32.

What could be preventing this communication?

Comment: It's hard to tell without having access to the tcpdump, but please verify that the sender address in the outgoing UDP packet matches the IP of the outgoing interface of the computer, e.g. is not something like 127.0.0.1 or the address of another interface of the computer.

Comment: The sender address is 10.0.0.160 which is the (local) IP address of the client computer. However, I just realized that the Open Port Check Tools shows that the port 32 is CLOSED!!! I tried using other port numbers (like 52005) but for each and every port it reports that it's closed (I do port forwarding for those ports on the router, of course). Could this be a problem?

Comment: Just tried Simple Port Tester (PcWinTech) and it shows that the port I'm using is actually open (and I see the test UDP message coming from the PcWinTech in Wireshark). So, the port is conclusively open.

Comment: You write, that you do port forwarding to the external server on the client router. Try to disable this, because it does not make any sense: port forwarding on home routers is done for connections from outside to inside, not from inside to outside.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. After sending the UDP message, the client is supposed to get the reply from the server (I did everything according to the Java Tutorial example). That's why I forward the port on the client side as well. But port forwarding table affects only incoming packets, so it should not prevent the client packets reaching the Internet.

Comment: This should not be necessary, because a NAT router maintains a state so the reply to outgoing packets is forwarded back to the client. Anyway, if the forwarding is correct it should not interfere. But, unless you can make a packet dump on the outgoing side of the client router and the incoming side of the server router there is not much you can do to debug the issue. There might be middleboxes  on the path from client to server, which do traffic filtering.

Comment: I use Wireshark to observe traffic on port 32. On the server side there is no traffic at all. On the client side I see a UDP message sent from 10.0.0.160 (Src) to (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) (Dst) where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the server IP address (obtained by 'what is my ip'). I also did a test where I setup both the client and the server on the same computer. Again it works well when I put 10.0.0.160 as a destination address for the client message. But when I put my external IP address I get an ICMP message (received from my external IP address) type 3 (Destination unreachable) code 3 (Port unreachable).

Comment: Why do you try to send the packet to your (e.g. the clients) external address? It should be sent to the server and not to your router. Or if the server is behind a port forwarding router itself it should be sent to the IP of this server-side router.

Comment: I know, it was just a test. I think the problem is somehow on the client side because the server successfully receives messages from the PcWinTech site. It looks like the outgoing UDP messages are somehow being blocked. Could it be the ISP?

Comment: The ISP definitly has the power to do it and there are enough ISPs filtering traffic.

Comment: Steffen, I just asked another friend to run the client on his PC and the message went through! I will investigate what was wrong on my client but I think I can close this question. Thank you very much for you time and effort.